# Ассемблер на двух и более ядерном процессоре

Tags: ассемблер

Немного умею программировать на асме для микроконтроллеров AVR и 8051, и однажды родился вопрос: а как выглядит программа на ассемблере для двухядерного или более, процессора. Попытался себе это представить, и понял что не могу. Это однозадачная штука, как ни крути. В голове не укладывается, ни как это писать, ни как это транслировать. Объясните секрет, пожалейте дурака.

Comment: Вы не поверите, но внешне точно так же, как и для одного. Транслируется, однозначно, так же. Если работаете под ОС, то запускается она на одном процессоре, а  потом делает системный вызов в результате которого какая-то ее часть (указанная вами, конечно) начинает выполняться на другом. Естественно, что хотя бы стек для этих частей должен быть в разных адресах. Если работаете на голом железе, то исполняться начинает на одном процессоре. Затем вы сами запускаете второй, указав ему с какого адреса надо начать выполнять инструкции. Это очень вкратце, наверное есть много книг, где все подробно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Windows усть такое понятие как поток-исполнения **"Thread"** (коротко - тред). Поскольку на системах х32 юзеру доступно половина адресного пространства из четырёх ~2 ГБ, то в одном своём приложении функцией `CreateThread()` мы можем создать макс.2000 тредов, т.к. в дефолте каждому из них выделяется по 1 МБ для стека. Теперь это приложение попадает в среду исполнения на произвольном компьютере. Если у него процессор 2-х и более ядерный, то системный планировщик потоков распределяет наши 2000 тредов поровну по всем исполнительным ядрам CPU, в результате чего они фактически исполняются параллельно по времени.

Здесь мы сталкиваемся с проблемой синхронизации работы всех потоков, т.е. чтобы не получилось так, что один поток что-то сохранил в глобальной переменной, а ничего не знающий об этом второй поток тут-же не подмял эту переменную под себя. Для этого существуют объекты синхронизации типа: семафоры, события, мутанты, эвенты. Поэтому в многопоточном коде советуют использовать только локальные переменные, которые никто у вас уже не заберёт, т.к. они распологаются в индивидуальном стеке каждого потока.

Если-же ядро у процессора одно, то планировщику придётся ставить в одну очередь все 2000 потоков приложения. В этом случае приложение остаётся то-же самое, только получаем иллюзию параллельного исполнения, т.к. треды будут исполняться в порядке очерёдности, по выделенному им кванту времени (в дефолте ~12 микро-сек). Вот скелет многопоточного приложения на ассемблере fasm:

```
.data
id1  dd 0 ;// переменные под ID потока
id2  dd 0
id3  dd 0
id4  dd 0
.code
start: invoke CreateThread,0,4096,thread_1,0,0,id1  ;// создаём нужное кол-во тредов..
       invoke CreateThread,0,4096,thread_2,0,0,id2  ;// 4096 - это размер стека в байтах
       invoke CreateThread,0,4096,thread_3,0,0,id3  ;// ThreadX - указатель на процедуру потока
       invoke CreateThread,0,4096,thread_4,0,0,id4  ;// idX - идентификатор потока,
                                                    ;// чтобы его можно было приостановить, закрыть и.п.

proc thread_1
;// ..... код потока
endp
proc thread_2
;// ..... код потока
endp
proc thread_3
;// ..... код потока
endp
proc thread_4
;// ..... код потока
endp
```